# Zend Studio apache server configuration directory

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

Just started using Zend Studio and I'n trying to set up debugging so I need to configure my local server. I've checked the Zend help guides and it simply states "Configuration Directory: The path to the Apache configuration files (e.g. C:\Program Files\apache2\conf)". Problem is I don't know what the 'path' to the Apache configuration files is.

I'm using Zend Studio on Mac OS X and Mamp to manage my localhost site and apache server.

Anyone know what the file path would be?

Comment: Perhaps `find / -name httpd.conf` can find it

Comment: I found Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf which would appear to be the correct file. However, when using the zend apache server configuration wizard I get the error "Installation directory does not contain valid Apache HTTP server configuration." and the 'Finish' button is greyed out.

Comment: perhaps you need a leading slash `/Applications/...`

Comment: or you need to enter it without the file name, only `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache`

Comment: For "Configuration Directory", I am providing a value such as: "C:\Users\[my_user]\[my_folder]\[my_folder]\UniformServer13_3_2_ZeroXIII\UniServerZ\core\apache2\conf". That is the location where I have my file httpd.conf. Nonetheless, the "Next" and "Finish" buttons are greyed out, and I see the following error: "Installation directory does not contain valid Apache HTTP server configuration." Is it because I am using UniServer Zero XIII 13.3.2 instead of installing Apache independently? UniServer Zero XIII is an equivalent to XAMPP, for example, that allows you to install Apache/PHP/MySQL.